# When div with class x is clicked, add class active to another div with class x

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is what I have right now:

```
    $('.slick-slide div').click(function() {
    var thisClass = $(this).attr('class');

    if ($('.experts-copy-block div').hasClass(thisClass)) {
        $('.experts-copy-block div').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    }

});
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<div class="slick-slide">
    <div class="alpha"></div>
    <div class="beta"></div>
    <div class="gamma"></div>
    <div class="delta"></div>
</div>
<div class="experts-copy-block">
    <div class="alpha"></div>
    <div class="beta"></div>
    <div class="gamma"></div>
    <div class="delta"></div>
</div>
```

So what I want is if `.slick-slide .beta` is clicked, then `.experts-copy-block .beta` gets the class active and if any other sibling already has class active, remove it.

Comment: And what? What's your question?

Comment: @u_mulder `so what i want is if .slick-slide .beta is clicked, then .experts-copy-block .beta gets the class active and if any other sibling already has class active, remove it.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.slick-slide div').click(function() {
    var thisClass = $(this).attr('class');

    $('.experts-copy-block div.' + thisClass).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: IT WORKED! I knew it'd be something simple in the end, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
$(".slick-slide div").click(function () {
  // Remove all the active classes.
  $(".experts-copy-block div").removeClass("active");
  // Add an active class to the clicked element.
  $(".experts-copy-block").find($(this).attr("class")).addClass("active");
});
```

Does this work?

Comment: @Pepo_rasta Sorry. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.slick-slide div').click(function() {
   var thisClass = $(this).attr('class');

  $('.experts-copy-block div.active').removeClass('active');
  $('.experts-copy-block div.' + thisClass).addClass('active');

});
```

I would suggest moving the 'class' to a data attribute though. Though code will need to change a bit.